# Should I compress the harddisk file in a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, compression

I have a virtual machine with Windows 7 32-bit installed, and the host is Windows 7 64-bit. I have chosen dynamically resizeable VDI disk image. After installing Windows on the disk image, it is about 5gb in size.

As I don't intend to use the virtual machine frequently, I'm interested in compressing the disk image to save some of my own disk space. But I'm very new to virtual machines and I don't know what is the best option.

1. Don't compress. It might degrade performance too badly, or VDI could already be a compressed format, and my own compression is waste of time.
2. Compress .vdi file in host Windows, through file properties.
3. Inside the virtual machine, go to its harddisk properties and select compress the drive.

Which option do you think it best?

Thank you.

Comment: It is a VM. You can easily make a backup and test points 1 and 2. As to item 3: That will compress the drive inside the VM, leaving a 5GB file on the host with more space available inside the VM. Possibly not what you wanted.

Comment: @Hennes But rather than waste my time doing that, I could ask if someone already knows.

Comment: The results will vary per machine and with the way you use the VM. E.g. if you usually max out the CPU in a VM and do a lot of disk access then the extra CPU needed to [de]compress might slow things down. Vice versa if you have a plenty free CPU cycles and you are IO-bound then compressing things might speed up.  Those are just two examples. In practice things will vary.

Comment: @Hennes My concern is compressing the 5gb image will take a very long time as it is compressing over the whole 5gb, while compressing inside the VM will be faster as the VM sees sections of the image as separate files and will compress them independently.

Answer (score 1):

Go with option 1 -  You should definitely *not* compress the VDI.

Option 2 - Opening, closing, and working with a compressed 5GB disk image will be noticeably slower.  It might even be painfully to excruciatingly slow.  And that would be compounded with a dynamically resizable disk.

Option 3 - This would not actually reduce the size of the the virtual disk, it would simply reduce the size of the *data* on that disk, but also slow it down.  Full disk compression, generally speaking, should only be applied to volumes that contain small to medium *data* files, or for not frequently accessed files.

Comment: The disk image is dynamically sized, so option 3 should reduce the rate at which it expands.

Comment: @NeilKirk Although I havent tested this, Im fairly sure your statement is false.  If you added a 1GB file, the disk would expand by 1GB, then the OS would compress the file.  Even if it compressed it to 500MB, the disk would still need the 1GB of space to uncompress and work on the file.

Comment: Assume your statement is true (I'm not sure it is; why wouldn't files be compressed/uncompressed in memory?) and I have 10 such 1GB files, and I only use 1 at a time. By compressing them to 500mb each, and then opening 1 file, only 5.5GB is used, as opposed to 10GB.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS compression inside a Virtual Machine (i had experience on that) is a really bad idea.

It causes CPU to high a lot and the gain in VDI reduce file size is not much, only 1/1.13, only a gain of 20% at top most i have seen (talking about a guest NTFS with compression enabled on all system partition).

To Shrink the vdi seach for a tool called "CloneVDI" i use version 2.51 (do not remember where i downloaded. It creates another VDI file from an existing one and have the option to "compact" it (aka, shrink).

With such tool, all the space not used inside the guest partitions will not take space on the VDI created, ensure to not change the UUID, then move OLD to a temp folder, move / rename the NEW one where it was, try to boot and if all goes well (the tool manual tells it can fail, but i never saw it falling) delete the OLD one.

Sample: After installing on a fresh Windows 7 all updates (using WSUS + OnLine) the VDI is more than 15GiB; after "cleanmgr" and other tweaks the partition tells 9.5GiB used, but VDI still is 15GiB; after using CloneVDI the file shrinks to 9.5GiB.

Oh! yes, activating the NTFS compression, that VDI after using CloneVDI goes to 8.4GiB, yes only 1GiB less, but time to boot multiplies by 10.

I mainly use CloneVDI with inmutable VDIs and when i need to "copy" VDI to another PC on another place (carrying it on a 64GiB USB 3.1 Stick)... since i now want / need to have (for software testing purposes) all XP,7,8,8.1 & 10 (Both HOME and PRO) (Both 32Bits & 64Bits), it makes 5*2*2=20 VDI files, worst i also need them as "clean" recent install state, only to last Service Pack and with all updates... that number multiplies by 3, so 60 VDI files... that 64GiB are not enough... i need a 300GiB USB HDD, so i carry a 500GiB Sata III 2.5 HDD in a 3.1 USB Type C enclosure, and i still use CloneVDI to shrink them.

If you are lucky, have USB 3.1 port on computer and a decent speed 2.5" Sata III HDD (1TiB or also 500GiB) that will be enought, the 3.1 Type C enclosures are really cheap (less than 20 euros on AliExpress) and works perfect, can fit in a pocket, etc... I hate USB type B conector (microUSB), tends to lost stability (it unplug by it self when you less want), since i use type C conector i had not had that problem (miniUSB connector is also very good, but do not let you get 3.1 speed, neither 3.0 speed, only 2.0 speed.

Note: Some wrongly call USB 3.1 to USB 3.0... ensure USB 3.1 Gen 2 (for really fast HDD speed) and yes, Gen 2 only works on Type C connectors, if enclosure connector is not Type C the top fast speed will not be really there.

Usb 3.0 and the bad called USB 3.1 (Gen 1) are only 5Gib/s (gigabits), while the USB 3.1 Gen2 (only with Type C connector) can work at 10Gib/s, in Windows host quite a bit more than one gigabyte per second (1GiB/s), so copying a VDI file of 10GiB only took less than 10 seconds.

Waring: USB 3.1 Gen 2 uses a lot of power, so be aware (most if on a memory stick) of the heat... a SanDisk 64 GiB USB 3.1 Gen 2 warms so much it can make you fell the same as putting your hand on a heated oven... so ufter unplug wait a little fot it to get cooler or blow air to it, etc.

If you can pay a decent 50 euros, get a USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type C + 3-1 Cable USB C to USB A + 500GiB Sata III 2.5"... you will see yourself not wanting "compression" again (remember to use CloneVDI tool after making important guest changes), you will see that with such Shrink / Compact will be enought.

Side note: Best practice... while using CloneVDI, use two different high speed disks (read from one and in pipeline parallel write to the other)... internal HDD and such 3.1 Gen2 Type C external one... after that copy back form one to the other. In really takes less time doing so, than doing read and write on same disk and after that copy it to the other disk (much less head movement)... unless you are a very lucky one with a SSD disk... if so put on external enclosure another SSD.

I have really had (as testing) on my hands a 1GiB storage (attached to a PCI express 3.0 x16 controller) able to reach a write sustained speed of 35GiB/s, yes 35 gigabytes per second... you can full fill the storage in 1/35=0.029 seconds (faster that most modern PC memory banks); obviously it was a "proof of concept" with liquid nitrogen refrigerated, bla bla bla. The idea is that will void normal memory "concept" of PC... and PC will boot as old PDA (instant), since no power will be need to hold memory... no idea when and if it will raise market (price? better not think of it, prototype cost more than $13M).

Till then the cheap way is Sata III 2.5 1TiB (or 1.5TiB) on an USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type C enclosure... and if have no USB 3.1 ports, buy a cheap PCI Express USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type C Card and a USB cable C-C for 10GiB/s transfers.

If can not afford such "speed" and need to stay on USB 2.0; my best suggestions are two: enable NTFS guest compression if you do not mind at all guest speed get reduced a lot, and after important changes use CloneVDI to shrink VDI size.

Please note: CloneVDI does not requiere you do anything prior on the guest (like zeroing free space, etc), it will do the full job, will see what sectors are really not used and treat them as if they have zeros so they do not go on generated VDI.

Pass CloneVDI using a really "slow" HDD (30MiB/s) on a VDI file of 15GiB and get a 9GiB (on same partition) tooks a little more than 25 minutes... while doing it from one USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type C enclosure to another one it tooks less than 30 seconds; that is why i talk so much about USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type C (10Gib/s)... waiting half a minute versus near half an hour.

I allways have all my VDIs in two USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type C enclosures (500GiB 2.5" HDD each one), so i have a BackUP an a really "fast" guest I/O performance... taking no space on internal OS HDD.

I will talk about such HDDs (mine are really expensive, i only use them for short tests), they can write at sustained near 6Gib/s (Sata III is the bottleneck), they are not SDD, but have multi-arms, so can write to more than one plate at a time, NCQ optimization, internal cache of 1GiB (not that ones of only 8MiB or 16MiB)... price... well near one thusand dollars each... i do not ike much the SSD and it low "erase" cicle count... more for an intensive (virtual machine VDI) use.

I would never put a virtual machine on a SSD, in two or three years the SSD can get damaged ("erase" cicles reached max). What i tend to use is a two really cheap 500GiB fast Sata III 2.5", each one on its own USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type C enclosure, so i get a write speed of near 200MiB/s; that makes CloneVDI 15GiB to 9Gib shrink to take near 3 minutes. Cheap and fast enought.

Hope i have helped you... sometimes it is better to use two small HDD (500GiB) than a USB stick or a big HDD (1.5TiB), enaught capacity for all VDIs and more speed... if combined with cloneVDI (read form one, write to another) it is ideal.

My main idea: change how to think... if the problem is "space", ok, do a little work (with no speed impact on guest) aka, CloneVDI to Compact/Shrink, and get two near fast external portable HDD that fits on pocket, so you can also hold the two last good know states of the VDIs; and of course use such extrenal HDD only for VDIs, so you ensure will have enought space for the future... and also have another copy of the VDIs on internal HDDs (if more than one PC), so you get... speed, low wait to transfer from one PC to another one, and 4 BackUp copies (if only two PCs, two internal, two external) and an extra 2 BackUp copies of "old state" on external HDDs.

In my case the 60 VDIs will never use more than 300GiB (internal guest max HDD size i use is 20GiB), actually it only tooks arround 200GiB, among i could i do not hold an old state since i use all of them as Inmutable, so i have near 280GiB more to grow (on a 500GiB HDD), imagine if i use a 1TiB ot 1.5TiB (what a waste of space), just for future windows versions.

I see with Windows guests, that the VDI files normally does not get bigger than 10GiB (remember i have them with default installation and only windows, no apps, etc), and if i put all windows updates (after cleanmgr, etc and CloneVDI passed) it grows to 13GiB or 15GiB (and grow is top limited to 20GiB, since i defined 20GiB for system partition).

That way i can test an app installer on all OS, recently OS installed, OS + Updates, 32Bit / 64Bit OS, windows version XP, 7, 8, 8.1 and 10... and see on which ones works and on wicht one fails, etc. Since i configured them as inmutable, after a power off on next power on first thing VirtualBox does is to through changes away, so i can test another app installer, etc.

VirtualBOX has a hidden feature, you can tell an inmutable HDD to not loose that changes when virtual machine is powered on while still being inmutable... so you can also test apps installers that need to power off the machine.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a summary of your novel.

Comment: I agree with @DavidPostill. When the OP tries to read your answer, after some minutes, he'll forget what his question was at the first place.

Comment: Editing out the factually inaccurate advice (ie ssd wear leveling) and offtopic information (anything about HDD types, sizes, interfaces, ...), this answer says "Do not use NTFS compression in the guest due to io performance losses vs minimal disk gains in an anecdotal use case lacking hw/sw config info. Use a TRIM/discard tool to free deleted blocks after updates." Incidentally, [CloneVDI lives on the vbox forums here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=22422) and vboxmanage includes clone functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Just check Pismo File Mount, great tool to "on-the-fly" compress with high ratios and low CPU use.

I have all my .vdi files inside .pfo files (with compression on), it compress a clean install of Windows (also if with UpDates) to less than 50%, so you gain more than 50% od space.

Such .pfo files are mounted on "C:\Volumes\bla_bla_bla.pfo", so it is only a matter of editing .vbox files paths to pint there.

I am talking for Windows Host, on Linux host i still have not yet used Pismo File Mount.

The .pfo files is mounted in read & write mode as a folder and you can put inside whatever you want (file & folders).

The warning: I do not know how to shrink the .pfo file

For what i use it mainly?: For inmutable VirtualBOX machines main .VDI, but not for vdis residing on Snapshot folder, that ones with autoReset="true" (since they grow and shrink).

Hope it helps!